# Где находятся настройки редактора Tiny MCE в джумле при управлении им из админки джумлы?

Tags: joomla, tinymce

Это нужно для того чтобы сделать свою версию редактора, со своими кнопками, чтением, записью итд,
но с возможностью управления из админки джумлы.

Answer (score 0):

Конфигурация лежит в таблице _extensions, в поле params.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]